# javascript is reading in only one file in ondrop event not multiple like it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, image-uploading

I just started creating a custom jQuery image upload script to run on a website I'm working on and the onDrop event only gives one file for some reason when I drop multiple. To be more specific, the alert(images.length); runs when I drop one files and it reads 1. When I try to drop more then one file the event never fires for some reason. My code is below and any help is appreciated since most of the sources I have read online explain it the way I coded it.

```
//Event for files being dropped on the upload area
this.on('drop', function(event){
    //Capture the event from the drop
    event = window.event;
    //Stop event propagation up the DOM tree
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    //Get all of the files dropped
    var images = event.dataTransfer.files;
    //Weed out non image files types
    alert(images.length);
 });
```

Here is the full code for the javascript

```
(function($){

//Initialization function for the plugin
$.fn.impulseImageUploader = function(options){


    //Appends in the file browser clickable area on create
    this.append('<input type="file" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; opacity: 0;"/>');

    //Event for files being dragged over the upload area
    this.on('dragover', function(e){

    });

    //Event for files being dropped on the upload area
    this.on('drop', function(event){
        //Capture the event from the drop
        event = window.event;

        //Stop event propagation up the DOM tree
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        //Get all of the files dropped
        var images = event.dataTransfer.files;

        alert(images.length);

    });

}

}(jQuery));
```

Here is all of the html

```
    <head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.impulse-image-uploader.1.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div type="file" id="image_upload_div">

</div>


<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#image_upload_div').ImageUploader();
  });
</script>

<style>
#image_upload_div{
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: lightblue;
        margin: 100px auto;
      }
    </style>
    </body>
```

JSFIDDLE link: http://jsfiddle.net/bv5pobz1/

Comment: Actually I did copy and paste it, but I missed the ctrl key when saving apparently in my editor. My bad. I wouldn't retype all of that code.

Comment: There is all of my code. You should be able to run those in local files and replicate the problem directly.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link, but it's not helpful since it doesn't allow testing of file uploads it seems. http://jsfiddle.net/bv5pobz1/